# How can I fix my formula to replace 'P' in time notation (where it should not be)?

Tags: excel, vba, time, replace

I have a simple query that corrects incorrect written time:
sometimes someone types '"' where it should be ':', so  a given time could become 13"34 instead of 13:34.

Perhaps because thick fingers. So I thought, I make the script correct al the mistakenly entered characters around the ':' key, including 'P' and 'L'.

```
Sub replace()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Hoofdbestand")

With ws

aantalrijen = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
With .Range("D2:D" & aantalrijen)
'.replace " PM", ""
.replace ";", ":"
.replace "'", ":"
.replace """", ":"
.replace ">", ":"
.replace ".", ":"
.replace "[", ":"
.replace "L", ":"
.replace Chr(80), ":"

End With

End With

End sub
```

However, I ran into a problem. In the table I have times like 15:49, 13:30.
There is nothing like 'PM' in there whatsoever:

[image]

But when I execute the query, this is the result:

[image]

Apparently, there was a PM string in the cell value somehow, although there was no 'P' found using the search.

Is there any way to get around this?

**edit:**

When I instruct VBA to replace " PM", the result is that the time changes from PM to AM: 13:00 changes to 1:00:

[image]

[image]

somehow, vba finds " PM" in the cell values where the Excel search function does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option I can think of is what you have already started doing:

```
.replace "PM", "MM"
.
.
.(your valid replacements here)
.
.
.replace "MM", "PM"
```